# Django-allauth links redirect

Tags: django, authentication, django-allauth

I'm using django allauth for my account management in a django project but the links tot the login, logout and register not redirecting to the appropriate pages for login, logout and register.

Comment: Can you post your URL's and HTML template so we can see.

I use the {% url "account_login" %} tag and it works for me

Comment: maybe some code may help

Answer (score 0):

you can see allauth original templates from this [link](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/tree/master/allauth/templates/account) for yourself to get the whole idea.

if you still had questions feel free to ask ;)